# using setTimeout in function that appends images

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm having trouble using this `append()` function in a `setTimeout`. If I remove the SetTimeout, then all of the images load. Once I put it in here, it seems like the variables become out of scope or invalid. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here?

```
//    thumbs[] is an array with image sources.

for (var imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < thumbs.length; imageIndex++) {

     var im = thumbs[imageIndex];

     setTimeout(function(im){  
         $("#a").append("<img class='images' src='" + im + "' />");
     },1000);

} // end for
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try to pass `im` to the `setTimeout` callback. Your anonymous function can read `im`, as functions have access to their parent scope. If you try to pass it like that, it won't work. `setTimeout` will call the callback internally, without passing any arguments. What you're actually doing is creating a new, undefined, local `im` variable inside the anonymous function, and blocking access to the variable from the outer scope. So this should work:

```
 var im = thumbs[imageIndex];
 setTimeout(function(){  
     $("#a").append("<img class='images' src='" + im + "' />");
 },1000);
```

**However**, your code is inside a loop, and just doing that inside the loop is not enough. Since the `setTimeout` calls are asynchronous, when they're executed `im` will be the last value from your loop (`thumbs.length`), always. You can avoid that by creating a closure. Sushil's answer is an example of that, so I'll show you another style:

```
for (var imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < thumbs.length; imageIndex++) {
     var im = thumbs[imageIndex];
     setTimeout(createTimerCallback(im), 1000);

} 

function createTimerCallback(im) {
    return function(){  
         $("#a").append("<img class='images' src='" + im + "' />");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this. In your case `im` inside `setTimeout` is `undefiend`.

```
for (var imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < thumbs.length; imageIndex++) {

     var im = thumbs[imageIndex];

     setTimeout(function(im){  
         $("#a").append("<img class='image' src='" + im + "' />");
     },1000, im);

}
```

IE dont support passing parameter in `setTimeout`
Try this if you want it to work across all browsers

```
   for (var imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < thumbs.length; imageIndex++) {

         var im = thumbs[imageIndex];
       (function(im){
         setTimeout(function(){  
             $("#a").append("<img class='image' src='" + im + "' />");
         },1000);
 })(im);

    }
```